# Django rest framework:UniqueValidator copare the field convert to upper case

Tags: django, django-rest-framework

I can save the `mac_address` to upper in database
And the `mac_address` value should be unique in database

But if the client send me a lower case json like `{"mac_address":'aa:bb:cc:dd:eE'}`
and my database already had `mac_address` with `'AA:BB:CC:DD:EE'`
But client still got `201 created success`
Why wouldn't my `UniqueValidator` work ??
Please help me find out

views.py

I try `ListCreateAPIView` and `APIView`
Both can't work well   I think the problem is `UniqueValidator` part

I find the [document](http://www.django-rest-framework.org/api-guide/serializers/#validation)  use `validate_<field_name>`  But My code not work

```
class DataList(generics.ListCreateAPIView):
    queryset = Data.objects.all()
    serializer_class = DataSerializer

    def perform_create(self, serializer):
        mac_address = self.request.data['mac_address'].upper()
        serializer.save(mac_address=mac_address, datetime=datetime.datetime.now(pytz.utc))
class DataList(APIView):
    def post(self, request, format=None):
        serializer = DataSerializer(data=request.data)
        if serializer.is_valid():
            mac_address = request.data['mac_address'].upper()
            serializer.save(mac_address=mac_address, datetime=datetime.datetime.utcnow().replace(tzinfo=pytz.utc))
            return Response(serializer.data, status=status.HTTP_201_CREATED)
        return Response(serializer.errors, status=status.HTTP_400_BAD_REQUEST)
```

And the serialize validator needs to convert to lower case first then query the database.

```
class DataSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    datetime = ReadOnlyField()
    mac_address = CharField(max_length=50,
    validators=[UniqueValidator(queryset=Data.objects.all())]
)
    def validate_mac_address(self,value):
        return value.upper()
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Your validator should be doing the actual validation:

```
class DataSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    datetime = ReadOnlyField()
    mac_address = CharField(max_length=50)

    def validate_mac_address(self,value):
        if Data.objects.filter(mac_address=value.upper()).exists():
            raise serializers.ValidationError("MAC address should be unique")
        return value.upper()
```

Comment: This works! Also, how do you get, say the foreign key details in the custom validator? Since we only pass the self and value, but not other key values, how can you go about getting these details in the function?

Answer (score 5):

define `valid_email` method into your serializer

```
class DataSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):

    email = CharField(
        max_length=255,
        validators=[UniqueValidator(queryset=BlogPost.objects.all())]
    )

    // your content and other stuff goes here

    def validate_email(self,value):
        return value.lower()
```

Comment: How to ````valid_email```` know to convert the ````email```` to lower??  I have a field name ````address````  and I used ````valid_address````  but not work

Comment: @user2492364  DRF executes valid_<field-name> if exists.

Comment: Please note that the correct prefix is validate_ and not valid_.

Answer (score 4):

Your **`UniqueValidator`** is working as its expected of it. Because the default lookup for **UniqueValidator** is 'exact'. Whereas you are in need of 'iexact' which does a case insensitive lookup. 
So change the `mac_address` serializer field to :

```
mac_address = CharField(max_length=50,
    validators=[UniqueValidator(queryset=Data.objects.all(), lookup='iexact')]
)
```

Note: 
Using the `validate_` prefix method will work but problems may arise when you are trying to use the serializer for partial update. At that time you want the serializer to exempt the checkup of uniqueness for `mac_address` field or at least exclude the current object from the queryset that you are putting the constraint on.